# How to use JavaScript on Xcode 4.3?

Tags: javascript, html, iphone, xcode4.3

I want to use javascript and html5 in xcode 4.3 environment with Iphone SDK.
How can we use and what template i should use ? Is there any tutorials for this purpose ?

Answer (score 0):

well it would work straight away with  UIWebview...So create an HTML5 page with Javascript and load it inside UIWebview.

If you have some specific requirement you can use PhoneGAP, Jquery Mobile, Sanchtouch like framework as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, just create a UIWebView, load the HMTL page you want, you can then call javascript methods on it

> NSString *html = @"<html>Some HTML here</html>";
>
> [webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
>
> [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"someJSToo();"];

You can then just add that UIWebview (in my example assumed to be pre-declared as webView) into your screen :)